# Converting Json object in to array using lodash

Tags: json, object, lodash

I am trying to convert my JSON result to an array to bind it to my Kendo controls.
The JSON result that I am getting is as follows.

```
"Issues": [
    {
        "Id": null,
        "Key": null,
        "Values": [
            {
                "Key": "Display Name",
                "Value": "Rya"
            },
            {
                "Key": "UserName",
                "Value": "RH"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Count",
                "Value": "350"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": null,
        "Key": null,
        "Values": [
            {
                "Key": "Display Name",
                "Value": "Mike"
            },
            {
                "Key": "UserName",
                "Value": "ML"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Count",
                "Value": "90"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The array that I needed to bind it to the Kendo control is as below.

```
 { "Display Name": 'Rya', "UserName" : "RH", value: 350 },
 { "Display Name": 'Mike', "UserName" : "ML", value: 90 }
```

i)I dont want to hardcode the strings "Display Name", "User Name", "RH". I tried v.Values[0].Key: v.Values[0].Value, but it didn't work.

ii) Also I will not know how many "key, value" pairs will be present, so I need to loop through the Values and generate the array instead of fixed

```
category: v.Values[0].Value, 
UserName: v.Values[1].Value,
  value: v.Values[2].Value,
.
.
.
score: v.values[n].value
```

Comment: provide a sample of what this new array would look like

Comment: What have you tried so far? Edit to include code and a proper language tag.

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal The new array should look like { category: 'Rya', value: 350 },
 { category: 'Mike', value: 90 }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using ES6, you don't really need lodash in this case:

```
var r = json.Issues.map(v => ({ 
  category: v.Values[0].Value, 
  value: v.Values[2].Value,
}));
```

http://codepen.io/cjke/pen/RprJdG?editors=0010

If want to use lodash or not-ES6, then:

```
var r = _.map(json.Issues, function(v) { 
  return {
    category: v.Values[0].Value, 
    value: v.Values[2].Value,
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to develop this in Angular2 using typescript.

Comment: If it worked make sure to mark it as correct so future readers of the question/answer pair can see what worked.

Comment: Hi Chris, a quick question. Here instead of category and value, I need "Display Name" and "Count". Also I don't want to hardcode the items here.  Because my json can have any number of fields. So basically like this -  { "Display Name": 'Rya', "User Name" : "RH", "Count": 350  ....... }, but dynamically because there might be a 4th field added.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - can you post a new question so it can be understood? Alternatively, perhaps update the question with an "edit" and the new content below

Comment: Hi Chris, Did you get a chance to look in to it.

Comment: I had a look, but I'm not sure I actually understand it. Would it be worth a new question?

Comment: I have posteed a new question. Please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42959518/converting-json-object-in-to-array