# Converting Json object in to array

Tags: json, ecmascript-6, underscore.js, lodash

From the below Json, I am trying to build an array as shown below.

```
"Issues": [
        {
            "Id": null,
            "Key": null,
            "Values": [
                {
                    "Key": "Display Name",
                    "Value": "Rya"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "UserName",
                    "Value": "RH"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Count",
                    "Value": "350"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": null,
            "Key": null,
            "Values": [
                {
                    "Key": "Display Name",
                    "Value": "Mike"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "UserName",
                    "Value": "ML"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Count",
                    "Value": "90"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Desired Array:

```
{ "Display Name": 'Rya', "UserName" : "RH", value: 350 },
 { "Display Name": 'Mike', "UserName" : "ML", value: 90 }
```

Here, there can be any number of fields in the array, but not confined to "Display Name" "UserName" and "Value". so I want to build that array dynamically.

Comment: There is no such thing as a *"JSON Object"* – JSON is always a string. There are no exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `"Issues"` is a property of an object you have.

You could use this ES6 code, using `reduce`:

```
const result = obj.Issues.map( o => 
    o.Values.reduce( (acc, {Key, Value}) =>
        (acc[Key] = Value, acc), {}));
```

```js
const obj = {
"Issues": [
        {
            "Id": null,
            "Key": null,
            "Values": [
                {
                    "Key": "Display Name",
                    "Value": "Rya"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "UserName",
                    "Value": "RH"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Count",
                    "Value": "350"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": null,
            "Key": null,
            "Values": [
                {
                    "Key": "Display Name",
                    "Value": "Mike"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "UserName",
                    "Value": "ML"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Count",
                    "Value": "90"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

const result = obj.Issues.map( o => 
    o.Values.reduce ( (acc, {Key, Value}) =>
        (acc[Key] = Value, acc), {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or in ES5 compatible code, and without the (bit obscure) comma operator:

```
var result = obj.Issues.map(function (o) {
    return o.Values.reduce(function (acc, kv) {
        acc[kv.Key] = kv.Value;
        return acc;
    }, {})
});
```

```js
var obj = {
"Issues": [
        {
            "Id": null,
            "Key": null,
            "Values": [
                {
                    "Key": "Display Name",
                    "Value": "Rya"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "UserName",
                    "Value": "RH"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Count",
                    "Value": "350"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": null,
            "Key": null,
            "Values": [
                {
                    "Key": "Display Name",
                    "Value": "Mike"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "UserName",
                    "Value": "ML"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Count",
                    "Value": "90"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

var result = obj.Issues.map(function (o) {
    return o.Values.reduce (function (acc, kv) {
        acc[kv.Key] = kv.Value;
        return acc;
    }, {})
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I think `()`-expressions like `(expr1, expr2, ..., exprN) //=> exprN` have been around since pre-es5; correct me if I'm wrong, please. Anyway, good answer ^_^

Comment: Yes, that is right, I just thought to write it in a more common (and elaborate) way as alternative.

Comment: @trincot have a similar case trying to figure out how to do. My existing array is [ { "Key": "WWC-383",  "Creator": "Indra", "Summary": "Test Summary",  "Created": "2016-12-19" }, { "Key": "WWC-382", "Creator": "Sukumar", "Summary": "Testing WorkDesk", "Created": "2016-12-15" } ].. The array that I need is [{ "title": "WWC-383", "start": "2016-12-19" }, { "title": "WWC-382", "start": "2016-12-15" } ] to supply to my calendar gadget.

Comment: `arr.map( ({Key, Created}) => ({ title: Key, start: Created }) )`, but really you should not ask new questions in comments, but press the "Ask Question" button ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Sure I will do that.

Comment: @trincot Have a similar question and created a new question as per your request. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43352917/highcharts-series-data-not-working

Comment: @trincot Had a smilar question I can loop through it and remove the last item, but thought you might have a solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667526/ignore-the-last-element-of-a-json.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use ajax to send:

```
$.ajax({

    url: your url,
    data: { Display Name: 'Rya', etc },
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {

        // what you want
 });
```

And use this function ( if you are using C#) to recivie:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject();
```