# Highcharts series data not working

Tags: json, ecmascript-6, underscore.js, lodash

My existing array is as below:

```
"Issues": [{
    "Id": null,
    "Key": null,
    "Values": [{
        "Key": "Display Name",
        "Value": "Rya"
    }, {
        "Key": "UserName",
        "Value": "RH"
    }, {
        "Key": "Count",
        "Value": "350"
    }]
}, {
    "Id": null,
    "Key": null,
    "Values": [{
        "Key": "Display Name",
        "Value": "Mike"
    }, {
        "Key": "UserName",
        "Value": "ML"
    }, {
        "Key": "Count",
        "Value": "90"
    }]
}]
```

My desired array:

```
[{
    name: 'Rya', 
    value: 350
}, {
    name: 'Mike', 
    value: 90
}]
```

What I tried:

```
Data.Issues.map(o=> o.Values.reduce((acc, {Key, Value}) =>
                                       (acc[Key] = Value, acc), {}));

this.donughtChartData1 = this.donughtChartData.map( ({UserName, Count}) => 
    ({ name: UserName, value: Count}) );
```

But this gives me:

```
[{
    "name": "RHanney",
    "value": "350"
}, { 
    "name": "MLuckenbill", 
    "value": "90"
}]
```

This has quotes and my highcharts doesn't work if there are quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last line of your code, add a `+` before `Count` so it gets converted to a number:

```
// ...
({ name: UserName, value: +Count}) );
```

How adding one character can bring the solution :-)

Comment: Yes :). Really appreciate your support.

Comment: one small question. Actually I need to use 'Display Name' instead of 'userName'. But as it has space in between, I am unable to find how to use it.

Comment: You mean instead of `name`? (There is no `userName` in the output object). You can use spaces in a property name if you wrap the name in quotes: `({ "Display Name": UserName, value: +Count })`.

Comment: I mean ""Display Name" filed instead of UseName like below.  this.donughtChartData1 = this.donughtChartData.map( ({"Display Name", Count}) => 
    ({ name: "Display Name", value: Count}) );

Comment: I don't understand: "Display Name" is not a key in your original data, but a literal value. You want that literal value always in your output, i.e. all objects with `name: "Display Name"`? I don't get it. Can you provide the desired output based on the sample data you have given before?

Comment: "Display Name" is also a key just like UserName and Count. Please see my actual Json. We tried with UserName and Count but the actual first key is "Display Name".  My desired output from my actual json -  [{
    name: 'Rya', 
    value: 350
}, {
    name: 'Mike', 
    value: 90
}]

Comment: Then do this: `x = x.map( (obj) => ({ name: obj["Display Name"], value: obj.Count}) );`

Comment: Thanks. you are a life saver.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141572/discussion-between-indra257-and-trincot).

Comment: added something similar. I think you can easily help me with this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43398137/sorting-json-data-based-on-a-field

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43856421/mapping-json-to-form-an-array