# Sorting Json data based on a field

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, underscore.js, lodash

I have a Json data that I need to sort before display it. My Json is as below. I need to sort them based on the ColumnLocation.

```
[{
  "Name": "PieChart",
  "Id": "1",
  "ColumnLocation": "0",
  "RowLocation": "0"
}, {
  "Name": "Calendar",
  "Id": "2",
  "ColumnLocation": "1",
  "RowLocation": "0"
}, {
  "Name": "FavouriteFilter",
  "Id": "3",
  "ColumnLocation": "2",
  "RowLocation": "0"
}, {
  "Name": "FilterResults",
  "Id": "4",
  "ColumnLocation": "0",
  "RowLocation": "1"
}, {
  "Name": "Watched",
  "Id": "5",
  "ColumnLocation": "1",
  "RowLocation": "1"
}]
```

i.e the sorted array should have items in following fashion

```
col : 0, row 0
col : 0, row 1
col : 1, row 0
col : 1, row 1
```

Comment: Don't see any json, just the "items in following fashion". However, the approach would be, convert from JSON to JS objects/arrays/whatever they are, run your sort (depends on what your JSON turns into), and there you go. JSON is just a string, to apply typical sorting algs you have to convert it (JSON.parse).

Comment: @TimConsolazio Sorry Just added the Json.

Comment: Posted the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for lodash/underscore. You can use [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):
Since your values are strings, you must first parse them into numbers and then compare:

```js
let a = [{"Name":"PieChart","Id":"1","ColumnLocation":"0","RowLocation":"0"},{"Name":"Calendar","Id":"2","ColumnLocation":"1","RowLocation":"0"},{"Name":"FavouriteFilter","Id":"3","ColumnLocation":"2","RowLocation":"0"},{"Name":"FilterResults","Id":"4","ColumnLocation":"0","RowLocation":"1"},{"Name":"Watched","Id":"5","ColumnLocation":"1","RowLocation":"1"}]

let sorted = a.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.ColumnLocation) - parseInt(b.ColumnLocation));

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: Indeed, this is the better designed compare function (subtraction returning a number data type) (+1).

Answer (score 0):

Short and sweet.

```
let arr = [{"Name":"PieChart","Id":"1","ColumnLocation":"0","RowLocation":"0"},{"Name":"Calendar","Id":"2","ColumnLocation":"1","RowLocation":"0"},{"Name":"FavouriteFilter","Id":"3","ColumnLocation":"2","RowLocation":"0"},{"Name":"FilterResults","Id":"4","ColumnLocation":"0","RowLocation":"1"},{"Name":"Watched","Id":"5","ColumnLocation":"1","RowLocation":"1"}]

arr.sort ( ( a, b ) => { return parseInt ( a.ColumnLocation ) > parseInt ( b.ColumnLocation ) } );

console.log ( arr );
```

Note that if you don't convert to a number, the sorting can not be what you expect.

Comment: This sort could be unstable: the compare function you provide to `sort` should return a number that can be negative, zero, or positive, but this function returns a boolean, so never a negative value.

Comment: There is no issue with primitive values, because they are indistinguishable when equal. But in general it is better to do the subtraction like in the accepted answer, as it will lead to stable sorts ("stable" only has meaning if you can distinguish values which are equal to the sorting condition, but would have other attributes for making the distinction). It is a matter of best practice.

Comment: So in this usage, there is nothing wrong with the sort. Thank you.

Comment: Ah I see the SO clique has found me again. Meh, enjoy your DV.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use _.sortBy ( http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy ) ?

```
var mysortedarray = _.sortBy(myarray, 'ColumnLocation');
```