# mapping Json to form an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Below is my Json

```
"Issues": [
    {
        "Id": null,
        "Key": "Project20",
        "Values": [
            {
                "Key": "Display Name",
                "Value": "Rya"
            },
            {
                "Key": "UserName",
                "Value": "RH"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Count",
                "Value": "350"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": null,
        "Key": "Project30",
        "Values": [
            {
                "Key": "Display Name",
                "Value": "Mike"
            },
            {
                "Key": "UserName",
                "Value": "ML"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Count",
                "Value": "90"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to map this Json to form the below array

```
{ "Display Name": 'Rya', "UserName" : "RH", value: 350, url: "Project20" },
{ "Display Name": 'Mike', "UserName" : "ML", value: 90, url:"Project30" }
```

Basically, I need to get the Key also in my array.

I tried

```
Issues.map(o => o.Values.reduce((acc, {Key, Value}) => (acc[Key] = Value, acc), {}));
```

this gives me

```
{ "Display Name": 'Rya', "UserName" : "RH", value: 350 },
{ "Display Name": 'Mike', "UserName" : "ML", value: 90 }
```

But I need the Key field also in the array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the initial value argument of `reduce`. So instead of `{}` pass `{ url: o.Key }`:

```
Issues.map(o => o.Values.reduce((acc, {Key, Value}) => (acc[Key] = Value, acc),
                                { url: o.Key }));
```

For those on IE, you'll need to use the ES5-compatible syntax:

```
Issues.map(function (o) {
    return o.Values.reduce(function (acc, pair) {
        acc[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
        return acc;
    }, { url: o.Key });
});
```

```js
var Issues = [
    {
        "Id": null,
        "Key": "Project20",
        "Values": [
            {
                "Key": "Display Name",
                "Value": "Rya"
            },
            {
                "Key": "UserName",
                "Value": "RH"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Count",
                "Value": "350"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": null,
        "Key": "Project30",
        "Values": [
            {
                "Key": "Display Name",
                "Value": "Mike"
            },
            {
                "Key": "UserName",
                "Value": "ML"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Count",
                "Value": "90"
            }
        ]
    }
];

var result = Issues.map(function (o) {
    return o.Values.reduce(function (acc, pair) {
        acc[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
        return acc;
    }, { url: o.Key });
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Does this work in IE? I couldn't able to test it. If it doesn't work, is there a tool to convert it, as I used similarly in many parts of my code

Comment: Did you get a chance to see my comment

Comment: Since you had provided ES6 syntax in your question which gave you a result, I had assumed you had ES6 support. See update to my answer, which includes an ES5 version.

Comment: Thanks trincot. I came to know that recently. Thanks for your help. Is there any tool where I can convert my other ES6 code.

Comment: Yes, there is: https://babeljs.io/repl/ Make sure in the presets drop-down you select ES2015.

Comment: Appreciate that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44465884/recreate-the-json-by-identifying-the-missing-values