# Recreate the Json by identifying the missing values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, underscore.js, lodash

I have a Json data that I need adjust before sending it to my component. My Json is as below. I need to identify the missing fields and move the below ones up.

```
[{
  "Id": "a",
  "ColumnLocation": "0",
  "RowLocation": "0"
}, {
  "Id": "b",
  "ColumnLocation": "0",
  "RowLocation": "1"
},
{
  "Id": "4",
  "ColumnLocation": "0",
  "RowLocation": "3"
},
 {
  "Id": "c",
  "ColumnLocation": "1",
  "RowLocation": "0"
}, {
  "Id": "d",
  "ColumnLocation": "1",
  "RowLocation": "2"
}, {
  "Id": "e",
  "ColumnLocation": "2",
  "RowLocation": "0"
},
 {
  "Id": "e",
  "ColumnLocation": "2",
  "RowLocation": "2"
}]
```

My required Json is:

```
[{
  "Id": "a",
  "ColumnLocation": "0",
  "RowLocation": "0"
}, {
  "Id": "b",
  "ColumnLocation": "0",
  "RowLocation": "1"
},
{
  "Id": "4",
  "ColumnLocation": "0",
  "RowLocation": "2"
},
 {
  "Id": "c",
  "ColumnLocation": "1",
  "RowLocation": "0"
}, {
  "Id": "d",
  "ColumnLocation": "1",
  "RowLocation": "1"
}, {
  "Id": "e",
  "ColumnLocation": "2",
  "RowLocation": "0"
},
 {
  "Id": "e",
  "ColumnLocation": "2",
  "RowLocation": "1"
}]
```

Here after (0,0), (0,1), property (0,2) is missing so I need to move it up and make it (0,2).. Same way after(1,0), property(1,1) is missing so it has to be (1,1).

I tried writing a custom function for this, but couldn't able to achieve it, so thought any map function that fits this scenario

I am getting gadgets information from the API. In some cases, some gadgets might be missing, so I need to pull there location up and draw the gadgets.

```
this.userService.getGadgets(id).subscribe(gadgets => { this.res = gadgets.map(function (v) { return v.ColumnLocation; }); 

// required logic ************/ 
for (let gadget of gadgets) {
 this.dashboardsText = ""; 
switch (gadget.Name) {
```

Comment: As in comments you indicate you need this to work in Angular2, please provide the code where you would need this.

Comment: @trincot So basically, I am getting gadgets information from the API. In some cases, some gadgets might be missing, so I need to pull there location up and draw the gadgets.    this.userService.getGadgets(id).subscribe(gadgets => {
            this.res = gadgets.map(function (v) {
                return v.ColumnLocation;
            });
            
            
// required logic ************/  

            for (let gadget of gadgets) {
                this.dashboardsText = "";
                switch (gadget.Name) {

Comment: Could you provide such info in your question (edit it?).

Comment: @trincot Updated it.

Comment: That code makes little sense. `gadgets` is a local variable, not available to the `for` loop. Also, the `for` loop nor the `switch` are closed, and I have no idea how that relates to the row numbers that you want to change.

Comment: So basically, gadgets contains the actual json in the question, which I need to modify to the required json. I am going to use the required json that is being generated in my code. So long story short, If I can convert the actual json to required json, my problem is solved.

Comment: But `this.res` will be an array with just the column numbers, so what use is there in doing the conversion on the rowLocation? And what is `gadget.Name`? Is it somehow relevant?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146453/discussion-between-indra257-and-trincot).

Comment: I just added the other code, as you have requested none of them will impact the actual question.I just need a logic that converts the actual json to the required json.

Comment: If you only need the logic, then the answer of NinaScholz works perfectly. The problem you seem to have, is to integrate it correctly into your existing code. Without understanding how your existing code relates to this, I cannot really help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the last column and row, then check if it is not the same column, then reset row counter.

Then check if `RowLocation` is equal to row counter and if not set the new value.

Finally increment row counter.

```js
var array = [{ Id: "a", ColumnLocation: "0", RowLocation: "0" }, { Id: "b", ColumnLocation: "0", RowLocation: "1" }, { Id: "4", ColumnLocation: "0", RowLocation: "3" }, { Id: "c", ColumnLocation: "1", RowLocation: "0" }, { Id: "d", ColumnLocation: "1", RowLocation: "2" }, { Id: "e", ColumnLocation: "2", RowLocation: "0" }, { Id: "e", ColumnLocation: "2", RowLocation: "2" }];

array.forEach(function (col, row) {
    return function (o) {
        if (col !== o.ColumnLocation) {
            col = o.ColumnLocation;
            row = 0;
        }
        if (+o.RowLocation !== row) {
            o.RowLocation = row.toString();
        }
        row++;
    }
}());

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You could use global variables instead if the closure, maybe this works for you.

```js
var array = [{ Id: "a", ColumnLocation: "0", RowLocation: "0" }, { Id: "b", ColumnLocation: "0", RowLocation: "1" }, { Id: "4", ColumnLocation: "0", RowLocation: "3" }, { Id: "c", ColumnLocation: "1", RowLocation: "0" }, { Id: "d", ColumnLocation: "1", RowLocation: "2" }, { Id: "e", ColumnLocation: "2", RowLocation: "0" }, { Id: "e", ColumnLocation: "2", RowLocation: "2" }],
    col,
    row;

array.forEach(function (o) {
    if (col !== o.ColumnLocation) {
        col = o.ColumnLocation;
        row = 0;
    }
    if (+o.RowLocation !== row) {
        o.RowLocation = row.toString();
    }
    row++;
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I am using this in my angular2 app, and I am getting the error, Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target. I tried removing the ()  in the last line of code, but then the logic is not working.

Comment: without knowing more, it is not possible to make a hint.

Comment: the structure is a closure over `col` and `row`, which need a call, but i don't get your error. does the above work here?

Comment: If I use your code as it is, I am getting an error saying "Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target" at line .forEach(function).. If I remove the () at the last line, the compile error is gone, but the result is not expected, The logic doesn't work

Comment: Did you get a chance to look in to this.

Comment: the last `()` in `}()),` returns fiunction with a closure over `col` and `row`, because they are needed for checking and updating `RowLocation`. if you omit the brackets, you get just the wrong function, which returns for every loop the closure, but it does not change anything.

Comment: Yes. But if I use the exact same code (with brackets) I am getting the above error.

Comment: you could try the second approach.

Comment: You mean the answer from the other user.

Comment: i mean, from my answer.

Comment: When I use the second approach, I am getting "Cannot read property 'col' of undefined". Sorry for troubling you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146438/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-indra257).

Comment: I defined them as global variables, still getting the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.move = function (old_index, new_index) {
     if (new_index >= this.length) {
           var k = new_index - this.length;
           while ((k--) + 1) {
           this.push(undefined);
          }
        }
       this.splice(new_index, 0, this.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
       };      

   var array, i;

   array = [{"Id": "a","ColumnLocation": "0","RowLocation": "0"}, {
   "Id": "b","ColumnLocation": "0", "RowLocation": "1"}]
   i = array.length;
   while (i--) {
       if (!array[i].ColumnLocation) {
       array.move(i, i+1);
   }
```

Comment: I am trying to implement this in my Angular2 app and I am facing issues implementing this,