# Ignore the last element of a json

Tags: json, ecmascript-6, lodash

My Json result from the API is as below

Json result:

```
"Issues": [{
    "Id": null,
    "Key": null,
    "Values": [{
        "Key": "Display Name",
        "Value": "Rya"
      },
      {
        "Key": "UserName",
        "Value": "RH"
      },
      {
        "Key": "Count",
        "Value": "350"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": null,
    "Key": null,
    "Values": [{
        "Key": "Display Name",
        "Value": "Mike"
      },
      {
        "Key": "UserName",
        "Value": "ML"
      },
      {
        "Key": "Count",
        "Value": "90"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I did a mapping by doing as below-

```
.Issues.map(o =>
  o.Values.reduce((acc, {
      Key,
      Value
    }) =>
    (acc[Key] = Value, acc), {}));
```

The result of the mapping is as below-

```
{ "Display Name": 'Rya', "UserName" : "RH", value: 350 },
{ "Display Name": 'Mike', "UserName" : "ML", value: 90 }
```

Desired Result:

```
{ "Display Name": 'Rya', "UserName" : "RH" },
{ "Display Name": 'Mike', "UserName" : "ML"}
```

In my requirement, I want to ignore the last element as shown in the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to add a filter before the reduce to filter out objects with the unwanted `Count` property.

```
.Issues.map(o =>
  o.Values
    .filter(({ Key }) => Key !== 'Count')
    .reduce((acc, {
      Key,
      Value
    }) =>
    (acc[Key] = Value, acc), {}));
```

You could also do this filtering inline during the reduction by not adding objects when `Key === 'Count'`.

Note: There is no such thing as the last property in a JS object. It is a collection of properties whose actual order is implementation dependent and unreliable. For example, printing your object in different browsers and platforms could give any order whatsoever, nothing guarantees that consistency.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is a combination of map, slice and reduce:

```
json.Issues.map(b => 
    b.Values.slice(0, -1).reduce((c,d) => {
        c[d.Key] = d.Value;
        return c;
}, {}));
```

Demo:

```js
let j = {
  "Issues": [{
      "Id": null,
      "Key": null,
      "Values": [{
          "Key": "Display Name",
          "Value": "Rya"
        },
        {
          "Key": "UserName",
          "Value": "RH"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Count",
          "Value": "350"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": null,
      "Key": null,
      "Values": [{
          "Key": "Display Name",
          "Value": "Mike"
        },
        {
          "Key": "UserName",
          "Value": "ML"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Count",
          "Value": "90"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

let r = j.Issues.map(b =>
  b.Values.slice(0, -1).reduce((c, d) => {
    c[d.Key] = d.Value;
    return c;
  }, {}));
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the last element regardless of how many items in the array I would favor something like this:

```
let result = data.Issues.map(issue => {
    let temp = issue.Values;
    temp.splice(-1);
    return temp.reduce((acc, {Key, Value}) => (acc[Key] = Value, acc), {});
});
```

Here's [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LgwpsLw3/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
.Issues.map(o => o.Values.reduce((acc, {Key, Value}) => (Key !== 'Count') ? (acc[Key] = Value, acc) : acc, {}));
```

full code:

```js
const j = {"Issues": [
        {
            "Id": null,
            "Key": null,
            "Values": [
                {
                    "Key": "Display Name",
                    "Value": "Rya"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "UserName",
                    "Value": "RH"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Count",
                    "Value": "350"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": null,
            "Key": null,
            "Values": [
                {
                    "Key": "Display Name",
                    "Value": "Mike"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "UserName",
                    "Value": "ML"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Count",
                    "Value": "90"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    }
    
    const r = j.Issues.map(o => o.Values.reduce((acc, {Key, Value}) => (Key !== 'Count') ? (acc[Key] = Value, acc) : acc, {}));
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(r, null, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that in a reduce method, the function is also passed in the current index and the array reduce is being called on. So if you want to ignore the last element of the array, you can do something like:

```
Issues.map(o => 
   o.Values.reduce((acc, {Key, Value}, idx, arry) => {
     if(idx < arry.length -1)
         acc[Key] = Value;
     return acc;
   }, {}
);
```